# Getting the possibly invalid displayed value of an input type time

Tags: javascript, html

I have an standard html input of type time `<input type="time" />`, where the initial value is `""`, it has 2 sections: an hour and a minute, and looks like this initially: `--:--`.
I need to get the displayed value when the user types something, however all the events I can listen seem to trigger when both the hour and the minute sections have at least partially been filled, the `input` event and the like.

The only events which triggers on keypresses are the `keyup`, `keydown`, `keypress`, etc. events. When those happen and the value shows `1-:--` for example, or `11:--`, meaning that only the hour has been filled, but not the minute, the `event.target.value` is still `""`. Is there a way of getting the value displayed by the browser in these cases where only the hour or the minute sections are filled? A requirement is that the other one has to be "--", so I can't set a different initial value.

Comment: Maybe set your time to `00:00` by default, then it can never be filled with `-` and it will always be a valid time? I'm pretty sure you are getting an empty value because parsing it as a time has failed.

Comment: That's the thing @somethinghere, the default value has to be `--:--`, it's a hard requirement

Comment: It's not possible to do so, you can display or get the value once it has been completely filled , but if you want to have a work around this consider using separate custom inputs for hour and minute values.

Comment: How can that even be a hard requirement? `--` _are not numbers_, what do you expect the browser to do with such a time? In those cases, indeed, the only solution is building it yourself with two inputs and then parsing it yourself. A lot of work, so I hope the one requiring you has some good reasons.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a start. You will need to handle backspaces etc.

Sounds like it is not worth it

```js
// testing
const time = document.querySelector('input[type=time');
time.addEventListener('input',e => console.log('input',time.value));
time.addEventListener('keypress',e => console.log('keypress',e.code,e.key,time.value));
time.addEventListener('keydown',e => console.log('keydown',e.code,e.key,time.value));
time.addEventListener('keyup',e => console.log('keyup',e.code,e.key,time.value));

// Conclusion: only keydown will capture the tab, arrows, backspace etc

let capture;
let lastCode;
let minSec = [];
time.addEventListener('keydown',e => {
  const val = e.target.value;
  let code = e.code;
  let key = e.key;
  if (val) {
    capture = val;
    console.log({capture});
    return; 
  }
  if (lastCode === "Tab" || minSec.length === 1) minSec[1] = key;
  else (minSec[0] ??= []).push(key)
  console.log({minSec});
  capture = minSec.join(':')
});
```

```html
<input type="time" />
```

Comment: Thanks, indeed not worth it, especially with all the complications. For example it seems you can't tell whether the user focused on the hour or on the minute part of the input when the `keydown` event fires. And there are other scenarios too where it's impossible to determine the state. Clicking around in the input parts can also throw it off balance